Aurora - password authentication failed for user "postgres" - after password rotation
I'm using python lambda functions. In the beginning of the file I call this function:
def create_db_engines():
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=os.environ['region']
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=os.environ['rds_credentials']
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print('ERROR getting secret ' + str(e))
        raise e
 # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
    secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    username = secret['username']
    password = secret['password']
    print('password:' + password) # added temporarily for debugging
    engine = create_engine(
        f"postgresql://{username}:{password}@{os.environ['db_endpoint']}/postgres")

    engine_async = create_async_engine(
        f"postgresql+asyncpg://{username}:{password}@{os.environ['db_endpoint']}/postgres")
    return engine, engine_async


I see in the log that the password is correct and I'm able to connect with it in pgadmin.
But I still get the error "password authentication failed for user "postgres"" and I don't know why.
If I rotate the password in rds it works ok, but it stops working in the next rotation.

what do you mean by this:  If I rotate the password in rds it works ok, but it stops working in the next rotation. do you mean that you only have the issue that the Lambda function is not able to connect after the rotation? and when you use the same new rotated password manually, you can connect normally?

I mean that the problem happens when the password is rotated automatically by rds, and rotating it manually in the console solves the issue, until the next time the password is rotated automatically by rds. It worked fine for a year, but lately this problem has started.

If the issue occurs only after you rotate the password directly, and after sometime you can connect without any problem, the issue can be with the connection pool that hold stale connections, which can persist and reuse the old password. to fix it add the pool_pre_ping option when creating the engine. It checks connections before using them.
engine_async = create_async_engine(
    f"postgresql+asyncpg://{username}:{password}@{os.environ['db_endpoint']}/postgres",
    pool_pre_ping=True
)

This ensures that stale connections are discarded and fresh ones are created.
BUT, if when you rotate the password, the new password doesn't work manually also, then you need to check your rotation function, and make sure it is updating RDS credentials correctly.

No, the issue is solved if I rotate it directly, but happens again after the next automatic rotation.

Manual rotation and automatic rotation uses the same function, but the rotation function add another version to your password SECRETCURRENT and another one. Check the lambda code you should see an issue with you rotation function.

I don't have a rotation function, it's an rds / secrets manager feature. And any way I print the password and I see the code gets the correct one.

yes, the secret manager, uses a lambda function to rotate RDS passwords. you can update it, you can fix it, and you can see the logs
